# Infinite sum of fractions

Tags: number-theory

Lets formulate the following series of fractions 
a_1/b_1 ,a_2=a_1+1/ b_2=a_1+b_1+2, a_3=a_2+1/b_3=a_2+b_2+2 and so on.If a_1=2 and b_1=4 we have the following series of fractions.2/4+3/8+4/13+5/19+6/26+7/34+.....
How do we prove the infinite sum of these fractions diverges?

Comment: You're notation is confusing.  Are you defining $$a_n = a_{n-1} + 1 \qquad b_n = a_{n-1} + b_{n-1} + 2 $$and considering the fractions $a_n / b_n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $n^{th}$ term in the series is given by $x_n = \dfrac{n+1}{(n+1)(n+4)/2-1} = \dfrac{2(n+1)}{n^2 + 5n + 2}$. Note that $$\dfrac{(n+1)}{n^2 + 5n + 2} \geq \dfrac12 \dfrac1{n+1}$$
Hence, $x_n \geq \dfrac1{n+1}$. Hence, we get that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n+1}$$
Hence, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean the recurrence in my comment, we can [solve the recursion exactly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5Bn%5D%20=%20a%5Bn-1%5D%20%2b%201%20and%20b%5Bn%5D%20=%20a%5Bn-1%5D%20%2b%20b%5Bn-1%5D%20%2b%202) using standard techniques for solving difference equations, or writing out the first few terms and seeing a pattern.

A shorter argument would observe that $a_n$ grows linearly in $n$. $b_n$ grows like the summation of something that grows linearly, and so $b_n$ should grow quadratically.

Therefore, $a_n / b_n$ shrinks like $1/n$, and so the sum should diverge.